# Does the vue.js work properly on wkwebview

Tags: ios, vue.js, wkwebview

Does the vue.js work properly on wkwebview? I understand it just a javascript when compiled but i want to make it quite sure about.

Our team is planning to make some part of our iOS app's content by web using vue.js and display it from iOS app using wkwebview.

Since our team has no experience using vue.js before nor displaying web page using vue.js from wkwebview. Just in advance to start making contents using vue.js we really would like to make sure.

We've tested to display sample page using vue.js from wkwebview and had no problem.

We're also planning to use Firebase Cloud Firestore with vue.js.

Comment: I am also looking for answer to same question. Seems to be there has been no issue using vue application in webview. But are there any road blockages with this approach? How do you plan to do SSO, localization and notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Vue works just fine in wkwebview.

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue and it was coming out blank.
You need to make the following change -
In index.html  we had links  like "src="/js/chunk-xxx.78xe86ad.js",you need to take out the 1st "/" in the links. Works like a Charm!!!